# New environment with center and parsep

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I want to make a new environment where the content is centered and where I can specify a local parsep value.

My attempt to make this work is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}                                                           

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myenv}[1]{%
    \center %
    \begingroup %
    \setlength{\parsep}{#1} %
}{%
    \endgroup %
    \endcenter %
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\begin{myenv}{1cm}
  Hello

  world
\end{myenv}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

This environment centers "Hello" and "world" as desired, but with the same paragraph spacing as between lipsum[1] and lipsum[2] and I want it to be 1 cm (in this example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `center` environment you're using is defined in terms of `trivlist` that is unaffected by settings to `\parsep`. You need a full `list` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}                                                           

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myenv}[1]
  {\list{}{%
     \setlength{\parsep}{#1}%
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}%
   }\centering\item\relax}
  {\endlist}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{myenv}{1cm}
  Hello

  world
\end{myenv}
\begin{center}
Hello

world
\end{center}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

I've added a `center` environment for comparison.

[image]

---

Be careful with the `%` you use for line endings: in your `\center` line it's not needed, while the space before `%` in the `\setlength` line *might* introduce a spurious space (it doesn't in this particular case, because TeX processes it in vertical mode). The `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` tokens are not necessary, because every environment already provides them implicitly; thus any (local) assignment performed in `myenv` will disappear when `\end{myenv}` is processed.

Comment: Thanks for all the nice suggestions! And good point about the comments/% - I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 4):

Dont's leave a space before the `%` at the end of line otherwise you force exactly the effect that percent at end of line is trying to avoid, extra space tokens in the definition. Also whenever you change paragraph settings you need to make sure the paragraph ends *before* the group resets the settings. Finally `\parsep` is a parameter to latex list environments, you want `\parskip` here.

```
\documentclass{article}                                                           

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myenv}[1]{%
    \center %
    \setlength{\parskip}{#1}%
}{%
    \endcenter %
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\begin{myenv}{1cm}
  Hello

  world
\end{myenv}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This adds a space also before "Hello".

Answer (score 3):

`\parsep` is an internal parameter used in lists.  Probably what you are after is the `\parskip` length.  You don't specify what spacing you want at the beginning or end of your environment, but here is one working example.  Note that we close the environment by adding a final `\par` command and inserting the vertical skip again.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}                                                           

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myenv}[1]{%
    \center
    \begingroup
    \setlength{\parskip}{#1}%
}{%
    \par\vspace{\parskip}%
    \endgroup
    \endcenter
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\begin{myenv}{1cm}
  Hello

  world
\end{myenv}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```